# spring - http://www.springsource.org/tags/form 404 error

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, maven, spring-form

Currently, I use a Maven project. I don't have any Tomcat server. I use the local google appengine server to test my application.

I would like to use the spring tags, especially the 'form' tags.

On a forum(http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/74017-the-absolute-uri-http-www-springframework-org-tags-form-cannot-be-resolved), I heard that I had to copy the spring-form.tld file from the spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF. It's done.

But when I launch the appengine server and I go to this url : http://www.springsource.org/tags/form , I've a 404 error.

What does it happen ?

Do you have any solutions ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please add the link to the forum, where you heard that you only need to copy the tdl file?

Comment: I've added the link to the forum

Comment: The form is clear, you are missing the jar. Copying the tld is not enoght, because this is only the "meta-information", you need the implementation of the tags too.

Comment: That URL is just the XML namespace, right? So why are you trying to visit it?

Answer (score 0):

404 means that the specific path you are trying to access does not exist. 
So either it did not deploy properly or it is not stored where you think it is

Comment: My spring-form.tld and spring.tld are well in the WEB-INF directory

Comment: The different jar files required for spring are sitting in target/myGoogleAppEngine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib. This directory contains the spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar. When I add the following tag(<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springsource.org/tags/form" %>) in my jsp page, I've the following error : The absolute uri: http://www.springsource.org/tags/form cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Answer (score 0):

Add the `spring-webmvc-3.1.x.RELEASE.jar` to your application (lib folder), thats all you need.

In your jsp use:  `http://www.springframework.org/tags/form`

The tld file itselfe is located inside `spring-webmvc-3.1.x.RELEASE.jar` : `\META-INF\spring-form.tld`